# how to convert numerics to strings in the select statement of mySQL

Tags: mysql

Is is possible to convert a numeric and date to string as you issue a SELECT statement in MySQL?  Something like this:

```
SELECT str(a.Amount) as AMT, str(a.date) as Date FROM LALAZUK as a...
```

Comment: Isn't mysql provide output as string only???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `CAST`:

`SELECT CAST(a.Amount AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) as AMT, SELECT CAST(a.date AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) as Date FROM LALAZUK as a...`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Comment: See revised answer here, but it should be fairly obvious.